# Delete all records in a table of MYSQL in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I use wampserver 2.2. When I want to delete all records of a table in phpMyAdmin (select all) it deletes only one record not all records. Why it does not delete all records?

Comment: depends on your query, did you execute like this? `DELETE FROM tableName`

Comment: Highlight the table name and press `SHIFT-DEL`

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Go to your db -> structure and do empty in required table. 
See here:

[image: this screenshot]

Answer (score 241):

You have 2 options `delete` and `truncate` :

1. `delete from mytable`

   This will delete all the content of the table, not reseting the autoincremental id, this process is very slow. If you want to delete specific records append a where clause at the end.
2. `truncate myTable`

   This will reset the table i.e. all the auto incremental fields will be reset. Its a DDL and its very fast. You cannot delete any specific record through `truncate`.

Comment: Note that **truncate** will also removed **index**, learn this the hard way...

Comment: Can I do this using Python? I tried in PhpMyAdmin and it works flawlessly. But when I write the same command in Python, it gives me an error saying **command denied to user@localhost**. I researched and it is bcoz it wants permissions. But the same when I do in PhpMyAdmin, it does not require any permissions. How can I do this and why is this difference

Answer (score 169):

Go to the Sql tab run one of the below query:

```
delete from tableName;
```

[Delete](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html): will delete all rows from your table. Next insert will take next auto increment id.

or

```
truncate tableName;
```

[Truncate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html): will also delete the rows from your table but it will start from new row with 1.

A detailed blog with example: http://sforsuresh.in/phpmyadmin-deleting-rows-mysql-table/

Comment: Can I do this using Python? I tried in PhpMyAdmin and it works flawlessly. But when I write the same command in Python, it gives me an error saying **command denied to user@localhost**. I researched and it is bcoz it wants permissions. But the same when I do in PhpMyAdmin, it does not require any permissions

Comment: Keep in mind that is unsafe query: 'Delete' statement without 'where' clears all data in the table"

Answer (score 42):

Use this query:

```
DELETE FROM tableName;
```

Note: To delete some specific record you can give the condition in where clause in the query also.

OR you can use this query also:

```
truncate tableName;
```

Also remember that you should not have any relationship with other table. If there will be any foreign key constraint in the table then those record will not be deleted and will give the error.

Answer (score 28):

You can delete all the rows with this command.But remember one thing that once you run truncate command you cannot rollback it.

```
  truncate tableName;
```

Answer (score 19):

**'Truncate tableName' will fail** on a table with key constraint defined. It will also not reindex the table `AUTO_INCREMENT` value. Instead, Delete all table entries and reset indexing back to 1 using this sql syntax:

```
DELETE FROM tableName;
ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Comment: This is the proper answer.

Answer (score 4):

An interesting fact.

I was sure TRUNCATE will always perform better, but in my case, for a db with approx 30 tables with foreign keys, populated with only a few rows, it took about 12 seconds to TRUNCATE all tables, as opposed to only a few hundred milliseconds to DELETE the rows. Setting the auto increment adds about a second in total, but it's still a lot better.

So I would suggest try both, see which works faster for your case.

Answer (score 4):

- Visit phpmyadmin
- Select your database and click on structure
- In front of your table, you can see **Empty**, click on it to clear all the entries from the selected table.

[image: demo-database-structure]

Or you can do the same using sql query:

> Click on **SQL** present along side **Structure**

```
TRUNCATE tablename; //offers better performance, but used only when all entries need to be cleared
or
DELETE FROM tablename; //returns the number of rows deleted
```

Refer to **[DELETE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html)** and **[TRUNCATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html)** for detailed documentaion

Comment: simple and fast. and i love the shredder icon

Comment: Easy and simple.

Answer (score 2):

write the query:
truncate 'Your_table_name';